# As a C# beginner (mostly console apps) what files to upload to github

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github

I have enrolled in a course for C# Basics. Most of the course are exercises which are just console apps. However, I want to add them to my GitHub profile. Unfortunately, as already stated, I'm new to `C#` and `Visual Studio` and I don't know much. I have learned to create a blank solution and add console app projects for each of the exercises. Each console app has a folder in the solution, which name is usually the exercise name: `ex.DepositCalculator`. In the folder (DepositCalculator) there are two folders – `bin` and `obj`, as well as `DepositCalculator.csproj` file and `Program.cs` which appears to be the source code. I have no idea about the `.csproj`, or `bin` or `obj` folders, and this is why I don't know what to upload to GitHub. Do I upload only the `.cs` file, or I need to `.csproj`, bin and obj, or should I upload the `.sln` (which appears to be the solution)?

My whole folder contents with the `.sln` file:

[image]

`DepositCalculator` folder contents:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What .net files should be excluded from source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992532/what-net-files-should-be-excluded-from-source-control)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280351/what-files-for-a-c-sharp-program-created-by-visual-studio-2015-are-worth-to-be-c

Comment: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore may help as a place to start.

Comment: So, from what I've read I need the .cs, .csproj and .sln files.

Comment: @Azzarox, just add a `.gitignore` file to your repository like Retired Ninja recommended. GitHub even helps you with that. You can also check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143956/gitignore-for-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions